# How can I change the color of certain words in the input field in real time?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I need to make sure that when I enter some words in the input field, the color of these words changes.

How can this be implemented if `<color=red>example</color>` doesn't work?

Comment: It sounds like you are using the normal Input Field.  Switch to the TextMeshPro Input Field.

Comment: @hijinxbassist not sure here .. the input field might behave different? Try and make sure that `Rich Text` is enabled

Comment: @derHugo For the normal Input Field there is a warning "! Using Rich Text with Input is unsupported.".  Rich text does work for the TMP Input Field though.   Could be a version thing, tested in Unity 2020.3.42f1

Comment: Messing with color tags in input fields usually does weird things. especially since the user could type their own, causing extra pain. You might be able to use `TextMeshPro.VertexColorcycler`.